# How do I exclude/blacklist admin paths?

Tags: cdn

Is there still a way to exclude administrative paths from using the CDN module in Drupal 8?

It appears you have to use advanced mappings, but I don't understand how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not currently. As the UI suggests, the complex mappings can be set in the module's [install/config/cdn.settings.yml](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/cdn/tree/config/install/cdn.settings.yml?h=8.x-3.0) config file, but it only allows for segmenting traffic to different CDNs based their extension.

The `FileUrlGenerator` service object handling the [file URL rewriting](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/cdn/tree/src/File/FileUrlGenerator.php?h=8.x-3.0#n109) doesn't consider a path context while deciding when/when not to serve file from the CDN.

You could replace this service class via the [`ServiceModifierInterface`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21DependencyInjection%21ServiceModifierInterface.php/interface/ServiceModifierInterface/8.2.x) and its [`::alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21DependencyInjection%21ServiceModifierInterface.php/function/ServiceModifierInterface%3A%3Aalter/8.2.x) method with a custom service class that does consider the path context.

Comment: Pretty much the conclusion we had come too :(